# How can I get the value of a Symbol property

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

I have an object in NodeJS (a socket to be accurate).

When I print it, I see that one of the entries is this:

```
[Symbol(asyncId)]: 2781 // the numeric value changes
```

How can I obtain the value of such key?

I've tried `socket['[Symbol(asyncId)]']` but got `undefined`.

The expression `socket.[Symbol(asyncId)]` would obviously not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will not be able to access it directly by key, unless you have a reference to the actual: `Symbol('asyncId')`, because every Symbol is **unique**

> The Symbol() function returns a value of type symbol, has static
>   properties that expose several members of built-in objects, has static
>   methods that expose the global symbol registry, and resembles a
>   built-in object class but is incomplete as a constructor because it
>   does not support the syntax "new Symbol()".

What you can do is loop through the object's own property keys, using [Reflect.ownKeys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys), which will include normal properties & symbols, and then obtain that reference.

You can also use: [Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols)

```js
function getObject() {
   // You don't have access to this symbol, outside of this scope.
  const symbol = Symbol('asyncId');

  return {
    foo: 'bar',
    [symbol]: 42
  };

}

const obj = getObject();

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj[Symbol('asyncId')]); // undefined

// or Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj)
const symbolKey = Reflect.ownKeys(obj)
  .find(key => key.toString() === 'Symbol(asyncId)')
  
console.log(obj[symbolKey]); // 42
```

**NOTE:** The object can have multiple keys where `key.toString() === 'Symbol(asyncId)'`, this won't be usual, but be aware, so you may want to use other function other than `.find` if that's the case.

**NOTE II**: 
You should not change the value of that property, since it's supposed to be for internal access only, even if the property is not read only.

```js
function getObject() {
       // You don't have access to this symbol, outside of this scope.
      const symbol = Symbol('asyncId');
      const symbol2 = Symbol('asyncId');

      return {
        foo: 'bar',
        [symbol]: 'the value I don\'t want',
        [symbol2]: 'the value I want'
      };

}
const obj = getObject();

const symbolKey = Reflect.ownKeys(obj)
  .find(key => key.toString() === 'Symbol(asyncId)')
  
console.log(obj[symbolKey]); // the value I don't want

console.log('=== All values ===');
Reflect.ownKeys(obj)
  .forEach(key => console.log(obj[key]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj) and iterate over it

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) in advance and use it as accessor for the object.

> Every symbol value returned from `Symbol()` is unique.  A symbol value may be used as an identifier for object properties; this is the data type's only purpose.  Some further explanation about purpose and usage can be found in the [glossary entry for Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol).

```js
var asyncId = 42,
    symbol = Symbol(asyncId),
    object = { [symbol]: 2781 };

console.log(object[symbol]);
console.log(symbol.toString());
```

Comment: I don't have access to that symbol. I just receive a socket object.